# Кодировки в Java

Tags: java

Есть блок кода, который считывает строку из файла и строка будет на русском языке, но соответственно в терминале вместо русских буквы - вопросительные знаки, а на английском языке нормально выводить, я так понимаю проблема с кодировками, как можно решить эту проблему?

```
    public static void HabitFileReader() {
    try {
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader("C:/ProgramData/Tracker Habits/Habit List.txt");
        Scanner fScanner = new Scanner(fReader);
        while (fScanner.hasNext()) {
            Habit1 = fScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Line 1 - " + Habit1);
            fReader.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("\nFile read error");
    }
}
```

Блок кода для записи:

```
 public static void FileWriter() {
    try {
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("C:/ProgramData/KateProgram/date.txt");
        fWriter.write(General.Writer);
        System.out.println("File successfully write");
        fWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Program complete");
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File write error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недавно похожий вопрос задал, по по выгрузке из БД. В обычном ридере могу предположить, что файл, который находится в текстовом формате не UTF-8. Ты выложил код, где ты считываешь файл. Но нету кода где ты его записываешь. Конечно можно указать кодировку при чтении, но это лишние строки кода. Лучше сразу записать файл в UTF-8; Потом как вариант может быть в pom'е, но там по стандарту UTF-8. Маловероятно что там накосячил ты. Нашел пример в гугле:

Для записи:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = 
new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```

Для чтения:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```

Comment: Да, проще будет при записи сразу указывать кодировки, вот блок кода записи:

Добавил в вопрос  блок записи файла в коде.

Comment: А для FileWriter возможно сразу указать кодировку записи?

Comment: @Andrew нашел ответ, сейчас обновлю.

Comment: @Andrew вот как-то так.

Comment: Получается тогда запись нужно делать через BufferedReader, а не через FileWriter ?

Comment: @Andrew Лично я использую BufferedWriter и BufferedReader. Как другие не знаю. Главное проверку сделай, создан ли такой файл, если нет, то nameFile.createNewFile();

Comment: @Andrew посмотри еще обновленную версию try. Там удобно они реализованы. Даже потоки не надо закрывать. Все блок за тебя делает. Этот подход будет наиболее новым.

Comment: Попробую воспользоваться BufferedReader, ранее им просто не пользовался и плохо знаком с его работой, надеюсь кто нибудь даст информацию о том, как прописать кодировку в FileWriter

Comment: @Andrew  Я посмотрел исходники FileWriter, ничего не нашел. Если вы посмотрите класс FileWriter, то увидите: FileWriter extends OutputStreamWriter. Это означает что там весьма ограниченный функционал. А использование буффера предоставляет много некоторых полезных методов, которых просто нет в FileWriter;

Comment: Тогда пойду зубрить методы и работу BufferedReader, благодарю за информацию)

Comment: @Andrew Не забудьте про обновленный блок try (java 8). И как его применять при чтении и записи файлов. Удачи.

Comment: Можно ссылочку про обновлённый try? Я просто только основы изучаю и изучаю по старым книгам)

Comment: Аааа, вы наверно имеетe ввиду что можно закрывать поток чтения/записи через finally?

Comment: @Andrew я учился по ютубу. Там много всего интересного. Вам тоже советую. В книгах не все найти можно. Вот ссылка на обновленный try https://youtu.be/aHO60SmsfJA?list=PL786bPIlqEjRDXpAKYbzpdTaOYsWyjtCX